# wrong search result [MongoDB, Yii]

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm using Yii and yii mongoDb extension (YMDS).

I have a case when `->count()` return correct number of result but `->findAll()` no.

```
        // calculate total numbers of document
        Document::model()->setUseCursor(true);
        $total = Document::model()->count($criteria);
        Document::model()->setUseCursor(false);

        $criteria->sort($sort_by, $direction);
        $criteria->limit($limit);
        $criteria->offset($page);


        if (!($docs = Document::model()->findAll($criteria))) {
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'can not find docs');
        }
```

So in `$total` I see number 2, but `$docs` has only 1, what could be the reason ?

Comment: it is variable with number of limitation. in that case it is equal 20. $page is 1 $sort_by is EMongoCriteria::SORT_DESC, and you somehow close, when I comment line with ->offset, everything work as I expect :) went to learn that function more deeply

Comment: Yes problem was in offset, it was calculated wrong. Thanks @raina77ow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have misunderstood the `offset()` parameter:

```
$criteria->offset($page);
```

Offset skips the given number of results, so if $page is 1 (as per OP's comment), the first result will be skipped.

In actual use for pagination you want the offset to be something like:

```
$criteria->offset($entries_per_page * $current_page_number)
```

$current_page_number should be 0-indexed so if your $entries_per_page is 20 the offset for display pages would be:

- first page : 0
- second page: 20
- third page: 40

If you're using Zii widgets like [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) or [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) they inherit from Yii's [CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) pager class which takes care of offset calculations and more.

Comment: Yes this is what I had write in comment above, thanks for clarification.